# How to create batch jobs in Mysql?

Tags: mysql

I would like to create batch jobs in a Mysql database. To fetch data from child tables, and insert them into a *master table*, whenever the child table gets updated or new records got inserted.

How could I do this?

Comment: Do you mean a CRON or Task Scheduler job

Comment: or triggers? https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/triggers.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is called a trigger.

Triggers are functions executed when an update insert or delete action takes place on a specified table.

Read more here

http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-triggers.aspx